# What is the light within Ego's planet?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Vol. 2,

Ego says that.

> much of his power comes from the light within his planet.

Ego also explains that

> Ego created the planet out of cosmic stuff as a part of what was becoming his expanding self.

Ego also explains that.

> Ego has planted seeds all across the Galaxy that will enable his creation to envelope the entire Galaxy.  The seed that we see on Earth lools like light.

But Ego needs

> another Celestial in order to control the light enough to make the seeds grow to envelope the Galaxy.

In fact, Ego went to great lengths to

> Create someone with the Celestial genes required for the task.

**So what is the light within Ego's planet?  And what is it about the Celestial genes that enable someone who has the Celestial genes to manipulate the light?**

Comment: Isn't it literally his brain? Or at least, it's the neural activity within said brain? And I'm not sure that it's so much having any old Celestial gene as it is Ego and Peter specifically sharing the _same_ celestial gene, so they both have access to the same "light"

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I thought the brain was just an artistic representation of Ego. Was there really an enlarged brain floating through space thinking things into form? Maybe. .... But on the gene front, none of Ego's other kids had the genes. So Peter's mother brought compatible genes to the coupling. ... Perhaps from the genes that the Celestials left on earth in the form of the eternals and later the mutants.

Comment: Celestials are "brain-like" entities, so yes, Ego as an entity was something similar to a physical brain that eventually grew large enough for him to become aware of his own existence. It's not really explained why the Celestial gene only took hold in Peter, though it's quite likely that it's because Humans are supposed to have quite adaptable DNA. Eternals and Mutants do not exist in the MCU.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Not a brain-like entity. Consciousness. Very different. Yondu taught Quill that the power to take on Ego comes from his heart, not from his mind. ... The brain is just an artistic representation. Though Ego may have formed a brain for computational purposes.

Comment: The "light" is just a placeholder for Ego's collective powers and abilities. Ego was definitely a physical being, why else would it be possible for him to make an individual with Celestial "genes" capable of using the light as well just via plain old coitus? Moreover, if Ego was a consciousness who could exist independent of his brain, why would causing an explosion in his brain kill him, if all he truly is is intangible consciousness independent of a brain, shouldn't he be able to survive said explosion?

Answer (score 3):

Ego is a Celestial. The physiology of a Celestial, essentially “space gods,” is not entirely known for certain. But we have been sufficient observations to make some educated guesses.

> The Celestials usually appear as massive armor-clad humanoids of enormous size, with most of them standing two thousand feet (610 meters) in height and some even larger (Exitar stands over 20,000 feet high).
>
> <sub>[Marvel Database, Celestials](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Celestials)</sub>

What we typically see as a “Celestial,” however, is just their armor-clad form. This armor can be taken off. After Tiamut opened his helmet, he revealed his glowing face — suggesting that Celestials form may be comprised or partially comprised of energy.

[image: Tiamut, the Dreaming Celestial]

Ego, also being a Celestial is reasonably assumed to be of a fundamental similar nature then as the other Celestials, to the extent that spacegods have uniformity.

The unique feature of Ego is merely how he has chosen to manifest his armor shell. Unlike the other Celestials who choose to manifest a metallic-appearing armor in anthropomorphic bipedal human-shaped form, Ego constructed his “armor” in the form of a planet.

The Light within Ego’s “planet” is Ego. The Light is a feature of Ego being a Celestial, as other Celestials we have seen also manifest in form of light surrounded by an “armored shell.”

Comment: Ego doesn't appear to be the same sort of Celestial as the other that appear in the MCU. Note that he identifies hinself as being a unique being

Comment: Ego also identifies himself as a Celestial; so _if_ Ego is an honest omniscient information source (which he has not been) whatever definition of “unique” he’s using applies to the context of a class of Celestial beings (I.e. “every Celestial has their own unique finger print”), as well as then that the definition of Celestial must accommodate that common class of beings having an element of uniqueness. However, Ego has also not been honest.

Comment: Also just because a character says something is true, doesn't actually mean that it is w/in that universe. Just like people in reality have beliefs that may not be based on fact, in fiction, characters are not perfect and are not omniscient (except for those which are narratively explicitly stated to be).

Comment: @Valorum Ego *would* identify as wholly unique. It's his namesake. Other celestials were apparently just as "disappointing" as everything else. I'd suggest he'd make this conclusion regardless of his form or abilities. Even, that is axiomatic. He *couldn't* see it any other way.