# Is a Celestial a physical being or purely a consciousness?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, celestials

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159994/what-is-the-light-within-egos-planet) makes the assumption that Ego is purely consciousness and does not have any physical components, any references to his "brain" being some kind of abstract concept to make it easier for audiences to understand.

I'm of the opinion that Ego started literally as a collection of neurons or neuron-like formations that eventually grew until he became self-aware. To  back this up (with a spoiler),

> If Ego wasn't a physical brain or brain-like entity, why would something as simple as a big explosion destroy him and all his power?

So which is it? Is there any canon MCU info (since he's not even a celestial in the comics) to suggest whether or not Ego is a physical being?

Comment: Ego was not originally a Celestial in the comics.

Comment: Neat, I didn't even know we had a "celestials" tag. Also, I know, hence "his comic origins are very different", but you're absolutely right @phantom42, and I certainly could have phrased that better. I've made an edit.

Comment: I think the most obvious answer is that since we've seen a celestial "brain" -- Knowhere -- in the previous installment, (and it was very real and tangible), that Ego was indeed a physical being.

Comment: (1) In the comic books, there are several instances wherein the "bodies"/armours of Celestials can be a source of a residual collective of a Celestial's abilities after the Celestial in question has died.

Comment: (2) Instances like the alternate universe version of Iron Man wherein he makes an armour out of a Celestial's body which gives him additional godlike abilities, Knowhere's instantaneous teleportation due to the inbuilt "continuum cortex", and Knull using Celestial energies from a Celestial's severed head (that Knull himself severed with a single shot) to temper the weapon used to kill said Celestial; to make it Allblack, the Necrosword (which began as a simple appendage of his own being) comes to mind. It should be noted that the head used by Knull is what goes on to become Knowhere.

Comment: (3) Moreover, Tiamut's body was recently taken over by Mr. Sinister and repurposed to the extent that would suggest Tiamut is dead, but then again, Tiamut happens to be one of the most powerful Celestials and he recently received a power upgrade on top of that, so it's highly unlikely that he was killed.
There's also at least one instance wherein Celestials are referred to as living in hyperspace and their "bodies" being just conduits that enable them to interact with the universe(s) more precisely.

Comment: (4) So Celestials might be transcendent to their bodies after all, but we also know that their bodies are not simple conduits either as they themselves have exotic properties.
Their "bodies" are neither purely technological nor purely biological, however, there exist several instances in the comic books that lend credence to both analogies. Their "bodies" being conduits which can be repurposed and made into other things lending credence to them being technological and their armours having cortices lending credence to them being biological are the most accessible examples.

Comment: (5) Each Celestial has also always appeared in their same, unique armour and no Celestial has ever been shown switching conduits on panel. Tiamut's body being available might be a result of him ascending his previous state of being altogether, but neither this has been confirmed on panel nor his death. So your question isn't easy to answer, even wrt comic books. Celestials in the MCU have already been nerfed since they were shown as requiring Infinity Stones to destroy planets and also since Ego was killed by a simple glorified bomb. Let's see how they're fleshed out further in the MCU.

Comment: (6) Ego in the MCU, however, was definitely a physical being with esoteric abilities. Why else would a bomb be able to kill him?

Answer (score 6):

I think at this point, especially as of *Eternals*, that we can conclusively say that Celestials are physical beings. We’ve seen several Celestials now and all appear physical. We see Arishem and Tiamut in *Eternals* and the severed head of one in GotG2 which is known as Knowhere.

In *Eternals* it is even explained that Celestials are “born” from planets.

> **Arishem the Judge:** It is time for you to learn the true purpose of your mission. You were sent to Earth to bring forth the Celestial Tiamut. Every billion years, new Celestials must be born. I plant Celestial seeds into host planets across the universe. The planet Earth was chosen to host the Celestial Tiamut. In order to grow, Tiamut needs vast amounts of energy from intelligent life. The Deviants prevented this by consuming humans until the Eternals eliminated them. Now, the human population of the planet has reached the required amount. It is time for the Emergence to begin.
>
> <sub>*Eternals*</sub>

What isn’t clear though is if Ego was actually a Celestial or not but it would appear he might not be. He appears and acts differently to other Celestials we know of and his birth doesn’t appear to match an Emergence.

> **Ego:** I don’t know where I came from exactly. First thing I remember is flickering… adrift in the cosmos utterly… and entirely alone. Over millions of years… I learned to control the molecules around me. I grew smarter and stronger. And I continued building from there… layer by layer… the very planet you walk on now. But I wanted more. I desired… meaning. "There must be some life out there in the universe… besides just me," I thought. And so, I set myself the task of finding it. I created… what I imagined biological life to be like… down to the most minute detail.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*</sub>

However, since he had a physical brain blown up by an explosion that was him I think we can say it doesn’t really matter what he is for the sake of this question as he appeared to be physical in nature too.

Comment: In this case, it seems more like the term 'celestial' describes a class of being rather than a specific race. The Celestials are one thing and Ego appears to be another.

Comment: @Valorum well note that the only person to call Ego a Celestial was Ego himself IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

**Celestials can be either a physical being or purely consciousness, like Ego. Ego began as a spark of consciousness alone in deep space.** He gradually shaped matter into a physical form for himself, creating a brain and then a planet-sized body. This is according to the official book, *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)*.

[image: The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline description of Ego]

> ##### Dawn of the Universe | Ego Takes Shape
>
> Not all Celestials are born from the cores of planets. Some evolve seemingly by happenstance, like the Celestial known as Ego. At first just a spark of consciousness alone in deep space, Ego manipulates matter to construct physical neural-networks for itself in a large, brain-like receptacle, then assembles an entire planet layer by layer around that. While other Celestials exist in the form of colossal giants, Ego prefers to mimic more humble forms of life, creating avatars that look like "lesser" sentient creatures found on distant worlds.